# Need to sit for hamotzi?

Tags: hamotzi-beracha, mezonot-beracha

Is there an obligation or a custom to sit down while saying [hamotzi](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5)? What about for the other before blessings ([borei minei mezonot](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA), [borei pri adamah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94), borei pri ha'etz, and [shehakol nihiye bidvaro](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95))?

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/116914

Answer (score 7):

The Pri Megadim (opening to Brachos, 18) specifically states that there is no obligation to sit down for the Birchos HaNehenin (including the Hamotzi)

However, Chazal (Gitin p. 70) and so in the Rambam (Deios chapter 4 Halacha 3) state that for good health and Derech Eretz one should eat while sitting. And since bread is being eaten while seated, as stated in the Mor Vektzia (mark 8) that "all things that are being done standing, the blessing should also be done standing. But things done while sitting, it is not proper to bless while standing, **as in Birchas Hanehenin**, but [Bediavad](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702) [Yatza](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/608)"

Comment: This is true if you are just saying it for yourself. But if you are being Motzi others then you might indeed need to sit for Keviut.